# C++ - Fastest check array bounds

Tags: c++, arrays

I need a very fast way to check bounds of an array.
My current check bounds is:

```
template<typename T>
class SmartArray {
    //...
    int size;
    T* array;
    T &operator[](int index) {
        if (index/size!=0)
            throw OUT_OF_RANGE; //#define OUT_OF_RANGE 0x0A
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

There is faster way to check if index is out of array bounds?

EDIT:

My solution is making troubles with negative indexes.
There is a way to fix this?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector`?..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am creating interpreter ,I can't use any internal things like this.

Comment: Sizes and indices should be `size_t`, not `int`.  This is just a bad idea in general.  Provide a method like `std::vector::at()` which does bounds checking and makes it clear that it comes at a cost. Leave `operator[]` as fast as possible.

Comment: With modern CPU's and compilers, you'll be more hurt by `array[index]` than any number of checks on `size`. The reason is that after the first check, `size` will be in a CPU register, but `array[index]` might not even be in cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your check misses negative values: if the size is `5` and the index is `-1`, the result of the integer division is zero, but the index is clearly out of range.

You can fix this issue by making the `index` parameter unsigned. The type of `size` should be `size_t` as well.

Comment: Yeah I alright said that in the question. I need to this a solution.

Comment: @DividedByZero I think I answered before the edit. Now I edited the answer to address the edit in the question :)

Comment: Thanks! Wait I am beginner then I need to wait to accept an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, division is a slow operation, so I would avoid that.

I think a simple comparison will be more efficient:

```
index >= size
```

This would, however, miss the case where `index` is less than 0 but if you use `unsigned` or `size_t` for the `size` and `index` variables, that would not be a problem.

So it becomes:

```
T &operator[](size_t index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw OUT_OF_RANGE; //#define OUT_OF_RANGE 0x0A
    return array[index];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, don't use division since division is slow (plus it fails if `size == 0`). A simple

```
if(index >= size || index < 0)
```

will do just fine.

Comment: if size is 0 ,then it's will throw `DivideByZeroException` similar to my username :D.

Comment: @nneonnneo Not really XD. I have some questions before this question. BTW sorry this check is slow. (A lot of 'bounds objects' use this and it's kind of slow to my project.)

Comment: The *fastest* check would be to make everything unsigned, so you only need one check `index >= size`.

Comment: But If I want to do something like this: `class A {int Value;};` and then `A *a=new A();... SmartArray[a->Value]` It would be slower because it'll convert unsigned to signed.

Comment: There's no conversion if they're the same size type, only overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you limit size of the array to the power of two, you will be able to use masking. That is store additional value `size_t mask;` which is equal to `size-1` (`== 2^n-1`). Then check may be done:

```
T &operator[](size_t index) {
    return array[index & mask];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to check array bounds is to not check. Callers of `operator[]` should be responsible for ensuring that they know what they're doing and not call it with a bad index.